# mongo explain function in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How can I get my javascript code to receive the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) execution stats results to be stored / displayed to my javascript code?  My ultimate goal is to store the executionTimeMillis in a variable.

I know I can go into the mongo cli - and execute `db.collection.find().explain()` - I get the results there... but how do I get javascript to store those results?  I am using mongoose currently 
 / can't figure it out.

in my `.js` code - if I execute

```
db.collection('collectionName').explain().find({id: 1}, (err, doc) => {
    console.log('explainresults', doc);
  });
```

I get `TypeError: db.collection(...).explain is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Use explain after find

```
db.collection.find().explain()
```

Comment: That yielded this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'explain' of undefined`